# Typecasting and where in for loop

Tags: swift, swift2

I have the following scenario:

```
protocol A {}
protocol B: A {}
protocol C: A {}

let objects: [A] = ...
```

How can I loop through the array and only execute logic for the objects that are of type `B`?

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
for object in objects {
    if let b = object as? B {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I was wondering if I can use `where` to make this more expressive and elegant.

```
for b in objects where b is B // <- compiles, but b is typed as A, not B
for b: B in objects where b is B // <- doesn't compile
for b in objects as! [B] where b is B // <- I get a warning that "is" will always be true
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is also `for case` (almost the same `case` as in `switch` statements) so it would look like this:

```
for case let b as B in objects {
  // use b which is now of type B
}
```

Another nice expression is:

```
for case let b as protocol<B, C> in objects {
  // use b which is now of type protocol<B, C>
}
```

so you can use methods, properties and so on from both protocols at the same time

Answer (score 2):

`as? subtype` and its variants are a code smell. The other answers here will help you accomplish what you want, but I wanted to suggest that you move this logic from the `for` loop to the protocol (if it's possible).

For example, consider a `Shape` protocol:

```
protocol Shape {
    func draw()
    func executeSomeSpecialOperation()
}

extension Shape {
    func executeSomeSpecialOperation() {
        // do nothing by default
    }
}
```

Create three shape types that conform to it:

```
struct Circle : Shape {
    func draw() {
        // drawing code goes here
    }
}

struct Diamond : Shape {
    func draw() {
        // drawing code goes here
    }
}

struct Pentagon : Shape {
    func draw() {
        // drawing code goes here
    }

    func executeSomeSpecialOperation() {
        print("I'm a pentagon!")
    }
}
```

As you know, you can create an array of shapes:

```
let shapes : [Shape] = [Circle(), Diamond(), Pentagon()]
```

This approach lets you loop through this array without knowing their type:

```
for shape in shapes {
    shape.draw()
    shape.executeSomeSpecialOperation()
}
```

This has two benefits:

- Reduces coupling (your method running the `for` loop doesn't need to know what a `Pentagon` is)
- Increases cohesion (logic related to `Pentagon` is contained within that type's definition)

I don't know for sure that this will work for your specific use case, but I think it's a better pattern generally.

Comment: This assumes that the method makes sense for all `Shapes`. What would you do for example if you wanted to calculate the average radius of all the circles in the `shapes` array?

Comment: I wouldn't store heterogenous types in an array if I need to perform operations that rely on homogeny. You could, for example, have a separate `circles` array, and make `shapes` a computed property.

Comment: So then each time you need a list of all shapes, a new array would be instantiated?

Comment: Yes, although it would be easy to cache it if there are performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain that this answers your case - because you have something similar already - and I do not entirely understand what you do not like about your version. However this works in Swift 2:

```
for object in objectArray where object is protocolB {
    //print(object) // only objects conforming to protocolB
}
```

Here are my declarations:

```
var objectArray: [AnyObject] = []
// contains a mix of objects of the following 3 classes


class class01: protocolA {
}
class class02: protocolA, protocolB {
    func test() -> String {
    // required to conform to protocolB
    return "hello"
    }
}
class class03: protocolA, protocolB, protocolC {
    func test() -> String {
    // required to conform to protocolB
    return "hello"
    }
}

protocol protocolA {
}
protocol protocolB: protocolA {
    func test() -> String
}
protocol protocolC: protocolA {
}
```

> compiles, but b is typed as A, not B

That's the bit I don't understand. Mostly likely because I am being dumb. But the way I am reading this, your protocolB objects also conform to protocolA as defined. I have defined mine the same.

Comment: If `protocolB` would define a function `test()`, you wouldn't be able to call it on `object` in your iteration without typecasting `object` to `protocolB`, because `object` is of type `AnyObject`, not of type `protocolB`.

Comment: In the updated code, if you try to call `print(object.test())` in the loop you commented, you will get an error ('AnyObject' does not have a member named 'test()').

Comment: It works absolutely fine in Xcode7. Including `print(object)`. That was only commented because it was an e.g.

Comment: Of course `print(object)` works, because `print()` does take an `AnyObject` parameter. `print(object.test())` doesn't, because `test()` is not defined on `AnyObject`. The point is that you can't call `test()` on `object`, not that you can't print `object`, and you're never calling `test()` in your example.

Comment: Finally I understand. Thanks for persevering with me.